# PhpRenderer not rendering my view script from console route

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I've created a Console route on my zf2 application to dispatch an email via the command line. So in my action I am creating a new PhpRenderer as specified in the documentation (http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.renderer.php-renderer.html) to render my email template (replace variables etc) and dispatch it.

Here is the code I am using:

```
  $renderer = new \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer();
  $resolver = new \Zend\View\Resolver\TemplateMapResolver();

  $resolver->setMap(array(
    'mailTemplate' => $config['template']
  ));

  $renderer->setResolver($resolver);

  $model = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
  $model->setTemplate('mailTemplate');

  $model->setVariables(array(
    'recipient' => 'foo@bar.com'
  ));

  $emailBody = $renderer->render($model);
```

However it seems that the Phprenderer does not render any PHP in my `.phtml` file. The exact same code works correctly however if I execute it in a normal HTTP Request.

Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Have a look at `Zend\Console` and the `ConsoleRenderer`.

Comment: @markus Simply replacing the PhpRenderer with ConsoleRender does not work. I've also looked at the source code of it and I don't think it does what I need it to, but thanks anyway

Comment: This code works no problem for me, although you do need to provide the full path to the template to a resolver:
..\src\module\Aplication\view\application\email\tpl.phtml

Comment: Are you sure the route is working fine for your CLI controller? can you get it out output anything at all?

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the reply. It returns the template allright but no php is executed (and no variables replaced). It is like it is simply echoing the file.

Comment: I can run this exact code as is from a console controller with no problems at all, the issue may lie somewhere else in the application

Comment: It sounds like you http routes are setup correctly, but your console routes are not.

Comment: @Andrew Please write down your comments as an answer. I want to award you with the correct answer since you took the time to research my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that it's because you haven't set the correct path to the resolver.

For reference, this is the approach I took:

```
    // render HTML and TEXT bodies
    $basePath = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../../view/emails');

    $htmlFilename = 'body.html.phtml';
    $txtFilename = 'body.txt.phtml';

    $renderer = new PhpRenderer();
    $renderer->resolver()->addPath($basePath);

    $sm = $this->getServiceManager();
    $renderer->setHelperPluginManager($sm->get('ViewHelperManager'));

    $model = new ViewModel();
    $model->setVariable('name', $user->getName());

    $model->setTemplate($txtFilename);
    $textContent = $renderer->render($model);

    $model->setTemplate($htmlFilename);
    $htmlContent = $renderer->render($model);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. However I am still unable to make it to work even with replacing the TemplateMapResolver as your solution suggests. I've tried using exactly your snippet and simply replacing the template file, but still all I get is the raw .phtml file. (No PHP executions). Have you made this to work via a console route?

Comment: Can you put up a test project on github?

Comment: I think I've found the problem. It seems that there is something different with the PHP included in my MacOS where I am currently doing my development. When I use MAMP's included php binary it works as expected. PHP binary is version 5.3.15 on my MacOS. MAMP's 5.3.14 and 5.4.4 works properly. I've create a sample module however if you want to try it yourself.

Comment: I've awarded you the bounty for taking the time to try it out and write an answer. Thanks